# Akhq to display gzip compressed message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, akhq

I am using Spring Boot microservice with Kafka for receiving messages. I am at consumer end. At producer end, we have a .net application which explicitly compresses the message using gzip compression through code and sends the message in byte format. At consumer end, I am decompressing the message using gzip decompression in Java.

I am using akhq tool in-order to track the messages. Messages were getting displayed fine in akhq before compression. But after implementing compression which is done explicitly in .net, messages are getting displayed in bytes in non-readable format in akhq.

Is it possible for akhq tool to display the compressed message in readable format? I tried in google haven't got any solution so far.